# Converting executeQuery to executeUpdate

Tags: java, sql, sql-update

I am trying to write a program to allow the user to update a certain value in a column in an sql database. I was using `executeQuery` when I was writing data to the database and I went to copy and paste the same code to use when updating a value.

I changed the SQL statement to update the value and I read that I needed to change my `executeQuery` to `executeUpdate`. However when I went to change that I received an error saying that int cannot be converted to `ResultSet`.

```
case "G":

   System.out.println("Enter the player ID:");
   String playerId = FileUtility.getInput().nextLine();

   System.out.println("Here are the players");
   //theList = loadCampersFromDatabase(theList);
   for (Player camper : PlayerDAO.selectAllById(playerId)) {
       System.out.println(camper);
   }
   System.out.println("Enter the new amount paid");
   int newAmountPaid = FileUtility.getInput().nextInt();

   ArrayList<Player> players = new ArrayList();
   PreparedStatement ps = null;
   String sql = null;
   Connection conn = null;
   try {
      conn = ConnectionUtils.getConnection();

      sql = "UPDATE `Camper` SET `amountPaid`  where id like ?";

      ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
      ps.setString(1, playerId + "%");
      ResultSet rs = ps.executeUpdate();

      while (rs.next()) {

        int newId = rs.getInt("id");
        String firstName = rs.getString("firstName");
        String lastName = rs.getString("lastName");
        String parentsName = rs.getString("parentsName");
        int phoneNumber = rs.getInt("phoneNumber");
        String email = rs.getString("email");
        int amountPaid = rs.getInt("amountPaid");
        players.add(new Player(newId, firstName, lastName, 
        parentsName, phoneNumber, email, amountPaid));

      }

   } catch (Exception e) {
      String errorMessage = e.getMessage();
      e.printStackTrace();
   } finally {
      DbUtils.close(ps, conn);
   }

   break;
```

Comment: executeUpdate returns an int representing how many rows were affected, as opposed to executeQuery.

Comment: @BaSsGaz I don't need to return anything in the end, I just need it to update that column in the table

Comment: Your code is for results of a select query, you cannot substitute that for executeUpdate. You can either run the update before/after the query in addition or you can update the resultset instead of running the update.

Comment: @RyanBlanchard Then just use `ps.executeUpdate();` solo, then if you want to query for your loop, then use executeQuery!

Comment: @RyanBlanchard then remove all of the `while` code

Comment: Your update statement is also not valid sql, you need to,actually assign a new amount

Answer (score 0):

You have confused with executeUpdate() and executeQuery() methods.

1. executeUpdate():
   executes 'UPDATE' and other statments and it returns a int value,it tells how many rows are affected by your updated statement.
2. executeQuery() 
   -This method executes only 'SELECT' query and it returns ResultSet instance which can be used further to interate inside a loop(while) to fetch and display all the records generally using select statement.

I would suggest you to redo the logic of your method.
I could see your update query,you have only passed one value for 'id' in query and not for 'amountPaid'.
Rewrite update statement and use executeUpdate() method to do update.

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove the `Resultset` and its corresponding `while` loop as action queries (`UPDATE`, `INSERT`, `DELETE`, `CREATE`, `ALTER`, `DROP`) do not return resultsets, only `SELECT` queries. Below assumes you meant to bind *newAmountPaid* into query:

```
sql = "UPDATE `Camper` SET `amountPaid` = ? where id like ?";

ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
ps.setInt(1, newAmountPaid);
ps.setString(2, playerId + "%");

ps.executeUpdate();
```